# SP 2013 - Updating a multi-value lookup field via the REST API

Tags: 2013, lookup-column, rest, multiple-values

When adding a new item to list via the Sharepoint 2013 REST API I want to populate one of its multi-value lookup columns.

I've tried passing in an array of Ids or a string with separators but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 11):

I'm hoping your question was for a multi-select choice field, where the entries are simply text, not referring items in another list.  I was able to guess the answer from this [microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/office/dn531433.aspx#bk_ListItemCollectionRequestExamples)

If you look under the ListItemCollection resource for "POST request example: Create list item" they show the following:

```
method: "POST",
body: "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.Team_x0020_tasksListItem' },
    'Title': 'Teams incorporate feedback', 'AssignedToId': {"results":[1]},
    'StartDate':'2014-01-29T08:00:00Z', 'DueDate':'2014-01-31T08:00:00Z',
    'PredecessorsId': {"results":[4]} }",
```

The PredecessorId field is using the format you need for a multiple select field.

Generalized:

```
'<multi-select column name>': {"results":["<text of first selection to set>", "<text of second selection to set>", ...]}
```

If you wanted to clear all selections:

```
'<multi-select column name>': {"results":[]}
```

Comment: I've been looking all over for this answer. Thanks kimon! +1

Comment: +1. Just a note, in my case the `type` property in `__metadata` had to be correct. You get the type either `__metadata.type` from an item or from `ListItemEntityTypeFullName` on the list.

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget to put "Id" at the end of your column name.
For example:
if your column name is 'AssignedTo' you have to put 'AssignedToId'

Also make sure the ID's you are providing in the "results" array are int's and not strings.

Comment: PLUS 1: this was killing me (appending Id to the field name for the POST)

Answer (score 0):

Here i update the  list(dynamic list) by pass the users id into sharepoint person or group field column(Approver1) using array.

```
var arry=[10,15];
$.ajax  
        ({  
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('dynamiclist')/items", 
        type: "POST",  
        data: JSON.stringify  
        ({  
            __metadata:  
            {  
                type: "SP.Data.DynamiclistListItem"  
            },  
            Employeename:"Test" ,   //replace your column name
            Approver1Id:{results:arry} //column name Approver1 added with Id
        }),  
        headers:  

        {  
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),  
            "X-HTTP-Method": "POST"  
        },  
        success: function(data, status, xhr)  
        {  
             alert("ok");
        },  
        error: function(xhr, status, error)  
        {  
alert();
        }  
    });
```