# How to insert data into a SharePoint multi-select field?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, choice-field, jquery-ajax, multi-select

I have a form that has a few multi-select choice fields.  When I try to add an item, I get an unusual error below.  I am using the Vue.js framework.

> "value: "A node of type 'StartArray' was read from the JSON reader when trying to read a value of a property; however, a 'PrimitiveValue' or 'StartObject' node was expected."

Here's the code and the fields that are multi-select.

```
 $.ajax({
url: fullUrl,
method: "POST",
data: JSON.stringify({
  '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.RegistryListItem' },
  'Register': that.register,
  'RiskRegister': that.nextIndex,
  'Reopen': that.formatDate(that.reopen),
  'RiskOrIssue': that.riskOrIssue,
  'Status': that.status,               //<---multi-select choice field
  'ProblemT': that.probTitle,
  'ProblemStatement': that.problemStatement,
  'TaskOwner': that.taskOwner,
  'RiskOwner': that.riskOwner,
  'ResponseOwner': that.responseOwner    //<--- multi-select choice field
}),
headers: {
  "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
  "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
  "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
},
success: function(){
  alert("Item Added!");
},
error: function(data){
  console.log(data);
}   
});
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an working example to set value of a Multi-select Choice field. Insert it in a Script Editor and test :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  SetMultiChoice();
});
function SetMultiChoice() {

var listName = "ListTitle";

 var itemDetails = {
    "__metadata": { "type": 'SP.Data.GZTickerListItem' },
    "Column_Internal_Name":{"results": ['A', 'B']}  // Multi Choice Column where A & B are the choices selected 

};
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: JSON.stringify(itemDetails),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function (data) {

        //Perform Some Actions
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
}

</script>
```

To get the _metadata value specific to your list use the below URL in your browser and search for ListItemEntityTypeFullName:

```
https://site-url/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ListName')/?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Is this correct?  ```'Status': {'__metadata': {'type': 'Collection(Edm.String)'}, 'results':that.Status}``` I get an error still.  ```that.Status``` is an array from my multi select drop down

Comment: Is it different for SharePoint Online?

Comment: Tested it in my SharePoint online site and Updated the answer. Please check and let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your multi-select choice fields in below format:

```
'Status': {'__metadata': {'type': 'Collection(Edm.String)'}, 'results':['Status 1', 'Status 2', 'Status 3']}
```

**OR** Simply try using:

```
'Status': { 'results':['Status 1', 'Status 2', 'Status 3'] }
```

Check my answer given at [SharePoint Multiselect Choice field Saving using PnPjs](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/267789/sharepoint-multiselect-choice-field-saving-using-pnpjs/267791#267791) for easy format.

**Similar Questions**:

1. [SP 2013 - Updating a multi-value lookup field via the REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/83396/sp-2013-updating-a-multi-value-lookup-field-via-the-rest-api)

Comment: I tried doing that but I get this error now ```value: "Incompatible type kinds were found. The type 'Collection(Edm.String)' was found to be of kind 'Collection' instead of the expected kind 'Primitive'."```

Comment: Have you tried the 2nd/simple solution in my answer? Is data type of your column is Choice or Lookup field?

Comment: Yes I did.  It's a choice field allowing multiple selections.  ```'Status': {'__metadata': {'type': 'Collection(Edm.String)'}, 'results':that.Status}``` that.Status is an array.  Is that set up wrong?

Comment: If you are passing an array then check my answer given at: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/267789/sharepoint-multiselect-choice-field-saving-using-pnpjs/267791#267791. This should work for you.

Comment: Don't pass the `type` in metadata. Just pass the `results` array.

Comment: Ok.  I will try that later and let you know.   What would the ```'__metadata:'``` be used for then?  Thank you!

Comment: I notice in your other answer, you are using pnp and I'm not, does that matter?

Comment: No, it should work fine for you as well using SharePoint REST APIs. Is it working?

Answer (score 0):

Sample test script:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
CreateNew();
function CreateNew() {
    var listName = "11/25";

    CreateListItemWithDetails(listName, _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl, function () {
        alert("New Item has been created successfully.");
}, function () {
     alert("Ooops, an error occured. Please try again.");
});
}

function CreateListItemWithDetails(listName, webUrl,  success, failure) {

    var item = {
        "__metadata": { "type": 'SP.Data.1125ListItem' },
        "OData__x0063_1":{"results": ['t1', 't2']}

    };

    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {

            success(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}


})
</script>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help on this.  You are passing in a hard-codded array.  I am passing in what I get from the multi-select drop down which is in this form in vue ```that.status```.  It holds the array values. Can the array be passed that way?  I have everything you have, except how I pass the array but I get an error.